# "Interlacement" of transcendental numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Let us consider two transcendental numbers whose decimal representation is
$$
0.a_1a_2a_3a_4... 
$$
$$
0.b_1b_2b_3b_4...
$$
Is $$0.a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3a_4b_4...$$ also a transcendental number?

Comment: My guess would be: this is unknown.  I would say "interlace" the decimal representations,  not "concatenate".

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks!

Comment: Most likely no. If we de-interlace $\sqrt{2}$ to get two numbers, it's highly unlikely that either one might turn out to be algebraic! And question: if one were indeed algebraic, would the second one have to be too?

Comment: Maybe normality in base $10$ of both numbers is needed.